# Child div not getting parent div height

Tags: html, css, cordova

I have a parent div and it's content 2 child div, one is left side and second one is at right side.
When left side child height gets increases, right child height is not gets increases.
Please see image uploaded. Thanks

[image]

Comment: you need to show your html and CSS code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes now i got the correct answer. I am using table to find this type of look.

Answer (score 1):

check this fiddle : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cvxr31xo/11/)

```
    <div id="major">
    <div id="one">Hello big</div>
    <div id="two">World</div>
</div>

    #major {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 150px;
}

#one {
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    background-color: green;
    height: inherit;
}

#two {
    width:auto;
    min-width:100%;
    background-color: blue;
    height: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You should post your code at first**, and check your's selector specificity (do you have `.class` or `#id` for the child2 element with other styling in css ?) maybe inline style for child2 element or `float:` property (floated elements can't inherit heights, because they don't know the height of the centre content) or `!important`, `@import` rules that will override the styling.

Add the `height: inherit;` to child1 and child2 elements style, it will work.

@Charlie show you correct method, height will be inherited from the parent element.